# Caesar Cipher string length issue

Tags: javascript, string, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to build a encrypter & decrypter for my uni assignment based around a caesar cipher.

I have made a decent start but whenever I try to return the string length so that I can loop the encrypter for each character it returns it as null.

Here's my code

EDIT: I have included the finished code that works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Encryption version 0</title> 
<style>

body { 
margin-left: 15%;
margin-right: 15%;
}

#description {
font-style: italic;
font-size: 18px;
}

#instruction {
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the encryptor</h1>
<p id="description">Please type below the text you wish to encript</p>
  <input name="txt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="txt" />
    <p>And pick an encryption key</p>
      <input name="key1" type="text" maxlength="512" id="key1" />
    <button onclick= "enrypt()">Submit</button>

    <p id="word"></p>


<h1>Welcome to the decrypter</h1>
<p id="description">Please type below the text you wish to decrypt</p>
  <input name="txt2" type="text" maxlength="512" id="txt2" />
    <p>And your encryption key</p>
      <input name="key" type="text" maxlength="512" id="key" />

    <button onclick= "decrypt()">Submit</button>
    <p id="word2"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      //Script 1

      function enrypt() {
  var text, additon, encrypted, numb;
  text, encrypted = "";

  text     = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  additon = document.getElementById('key1').value;
  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    numb = text.charCodeAt(i);
    key = parseFloat(additon) + parseFloat(numb);
    encrypted += String.fromCharCode(key)
  }

    document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = 'Your encrypted word is: ' + encrypted;
}
      //Script 2

        function decrypt() {
  var text2, additon2, encrypted2, numb2;
  text2, encrypted2 = "";

  text2     = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  addition2 = document.getElementById('key').value;


  for (i = 0; i < text2.length; i++) {
    numb2 = text2.charCodeAt(i);
    key = parseFloat(numb2) - parseFloat(addition2);
    encrypted2 += String.fromCharCode(key)
  }

    document.getElementById("word2").innerHTML = 'Your encrypted word is: ' + encrypted2;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know i'm using inline css, this is just temporary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your fixed function:**

```
function enrypt() {
  var text, additon, encrypted, numb;
  text, encrypted = "";

  text     = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  addition = Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97 + 1)) + 97;

  window.alert('Your encryption key is: ' + addition);
  window.alert('Your original  word is: ' + text);

  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    numb = text.charCodeAt(i);
    key = addition + numb;
    encrypted += String.fromCharCode(key)
  }

    window.alert('Your encrypted word is: ' + encrypted);
}
```

---

*Old answer:*

You are trying to read the value of uninitialized variable `txt`:

```
letter = document.getElementById(txt.value);
```

You probably want to initialize it first:

```
txt = document.getElementById("txt");
letter = document.getElementById(txt.value);
```

Also, check for the length of the input text length, not the DOM element:

```
while (i < txt.value.length) {
```

Comment: Thanks I should have thought of that. still get the string length of undefined

Comment: I see, then looking into your code further, I noticed you are not checking the length of the string, but the DOM element. Check for `txt.value.length`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. now it says Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of null. I don't understand as I set the variable "i" with a value of 0 so it should read it at position 0 which is the first one. Right?

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a dream